# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.compare vs System.Web.Mvc.Compare

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4 Beta project fails to compile after upgrading to .Net 4.5.

This happens due to conflict between
`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute`  and `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute`

[`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute` MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Provides an attribute that compares two properties.

While [`System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute` MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute%28v=vs.108%29) says:

> Provides an attribute that compares two properties of a model.

What is the difference between the two and when it would be "smarter" to use each of them?

10x.

Comment: Does my answer help? If so, it would be great if you could mark it as the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Good question.  I was wondering which was smarter, too.

Comment: @Josh please see my answer for more detail on the subject.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

So, looking at the MSDN documentation and doing a literal comparison of the two classes, I noticed both classes are derived from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute. In fact, the classes are almost exactly the same. The only notable difference is that the MVC version also implements IClientValidatable which adds the following properties:

- FormatPropertyForClientValidation - (static member) Formats the property for client validation by prepending an asterisk and a dot.
- GetClientValidationRules - Gets a list of compare-value client validation rules for the property using the specified model metadata and controller context.

As for which class you should use, if the model will be directly bound to a view, use the MVC version so that you can take advantage of the client-side validation. However, if you're using ViewModels, you can stick with the ComponentModel class and avoid the unnecessary overhead of the additional properties. Your call!

- [System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute%28v=vs.108%29)
- [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

Microsoft Connect work-around is:

> Posted by GavK on 6/17/2012 at 5:13 AM
>
> I added a full reference to [System.Web.Mvc.Compare(...)] rather than
>   just using [Compare(...)]

Works for me in VS 2012...

Comment: -  still I do not understand what is the main difference between the two. YoYo

Comment: As indicated in my answer, the version coming from System.Web.DataAnnotations is extending the ComponentModel version to enable some web client functionality. When properties decorated with the System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute are bound to a Razor view, the view will be able to generate some JavaScript validation hooks. However, if you were to use the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute to decorate your properties, the view would not be able to perform client-side validation. You would be limited to server-side validation.

Comment: Didn't answer the question.  He's wondering which should be used.

Comment: It wasn't happy with me removing the using statement so I added the full reference on the member type, e.g. [System.Web.Mvc.Compare()]. When it was happy I used the feature to remove unused using statements, once done I removed the System.Web.Mvc prefix from the member type.

Answer (score 14):

Vinney nailed most of it with the exception of which one you should use...

The reason you have a conflict after changing your target framework to 4.5 is because prior to .NET 4.5 [there was no CompareAttribute class in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and the class defined under System.Web.Mvc filled the gap. Therefore, as an example if you were using `[Compare]` and `[Required]` attributes in your model class prior to updating your target framework you ended up with a conflict when you upgraded.

Assuming you are not using anything else in the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace in your model class, you should remove that `using` statement and let it rely on the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace. Unobtrusive client-side validation will continue to work exactly as it did before, just as it does for other attributes that you decorate your model's properties with from the same namespace (eg `Required`).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this bit, @jm2. Thanks for the correction (and the 'at-a-boy :)

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to be explicit about the reference, you can simply add this line:

using CompareAttribute = System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute;

Comment: This solution works IF you still need to have the System.Web.Mvc reference as I do in my class.

Answer (score 4):

Using Visual Studio 2013 (MVC 5 project, .NET 4.5) the IntelliSense suggests that `System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute` is **deprecated**.

I used `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute` and it works fine. 
It also **does the client-side validation**!

Answer (score 2):

On [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727650/system-web-mvc-compare-ambiguous-reference-exception), they also suggest another solution, which is to move the reference of the preferred namespace for Compare() inside the model's namespace. Eg. if you prefer to use Compare from `System.Web.Mvc`, use:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProject.MyViewModel
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
```

The compiler will search inside the model's namespace first.