# 'Confirm password' and 'Password' do not match. MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I can't localize validate: 'Confirm password' and 'Password' do not match. in MVC5

```
[Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")] //Why not display this message???????
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Please help me localize it.

Comment: Localization means to tailor you code to a specific language. Do you mean internationalization?

Answer (score 14):

You have 2 options to solve this bug:

**--Option 1**

Change:

```
[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

to

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Your custom error message")]
```

**--Option 2** (I recommend this one)

We need to update our ASP.NET MVC 5. In your Visual Studio go to the Package Manager Console and type:

```
PM> update-package
```

You migh get an error in the:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
```

That error is caused by the update in the internal structure of MVC 5. To solve that error do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23090099/2958543

Answer (score 6):

It appears that it is a known issue and is not working correctly at the moment - http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1401.

However a temporary workaround would be using the Compare attribute from System.Web.Mvc, which is marked obsolete. Here is an example:

```
using CompareObsolete = System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute;

...

[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
[CompareObsolete("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I am currently using this workaround until the official fix is available. Everything is working perfectly fine - I am using this attribute to localize error messages using Resources.

Just don't forget to update it once the official fix comes out.

EDIT: The issue has been fixed in the latest release.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two types of CompareAttribute. Looking at MSDN, the one with namespace `System.Web.Mvc` seems to be obsolete and they suggest using the one with namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.
Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

With Visual Studios, you'll have to be explicit with the annotation and add the namespace to attribute in the annotation like the following:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CompareAttribute("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

For more information, see also: [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.compare vs System.Web.Mvc.Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668948/system-componentmodel-dataannotations-compare-vs-system-web-mvc-compare)